# Как открыть SQL базу?

Tags: c#, phpmyadmin, sqlite3

Хотелось бы подключиться к серверу (phpMyAdmin) и сделать выборку необходимых таблиц.

```
    using System.Data.SQLite;

    [...]

    //private string dbFileName = @"E:\база.sql";
    private string dbFileName = @"Server=000.000.000.000;Port=3306;Database=DBName;User Id=DBUserName;Password=qwerty";

    private SQLiteConnection m_dbConn;
    private SQLiteCommand m_sqlCmd;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        m_dbConn = new SQLiteConnection();
        m_sqlCmd = new SQLiteCommand();

        try
        {
            m_dbConn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + dbFileName + ";Version=3;");
            m_dbConn.Open();
            m_sqlCmd.Connection = m_dbConn;

            MessageBox.Show("Connected"); // **Подключение происходит**
        }
        catch (SQLiteException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }

        ReadBD();
    }

    void ReadBD()
    {
        if (m_dbConn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Open connection with database");
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM description";
            try
            {
                using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(m_dbConn))
                {
                    using (SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(sql, conn))
                    {
                        da.Fill(ds);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
            }
        }
        catch (SQLiteException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
            m_dbConn.Close();
        }
    }
```

При подключении к серверу: В методе ReadBD, текст исключения: "SQL logic error
no such table: description".
При подключении файла (файл экспорта из phpMyAdmin): В этом методе текст исключения: "file is not a database
file is not a database"

Comment: Sqlite - локальная БД, нафига в строку подключения вставляете сервер и порт? Тем более такой смешной адрес `"Server=000.000.000.000`! Это как общий номер телефона на планете Земля, или выйти на площадь и начать орать на всех  Укажите просто путь к файлу.

Comment: Да, это заменил значения строки подключения.
При указании пути файла пишет, что такой таблицы нет.